# Angular change detection not firing

Tags: angular, firebase

I recently had an issue where I wrote an Angular service that monitored uptime of a remote service that was regularly updating its status in a Firebase Realtime database.

The premise was to watch for changes on the Realtime Database key and update and emit the status, by means of an observable, to subscribed components.

In addition there was a timer observable triggering every 5 seconds which checked the status - in the event that the server stopped checking in and it also emitted the status on the monitor observable.

In the component that was displaying the status the view was never updating. Even though the subscribed observable was showing the values were being emitted

After an hour or so of debugging including trying different components and means of passing the status it became evident that the change detection was not firing when triggered from the event handler for the Realtime Database event. However, it was working for the timer.

service

```
private monitor$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(false)
private serverManager = new ServerManager

constructor(private afb:AngularFireDatabase) { 
  afb.database.ref('Diagnostics')
    .on('value', data => {
      // evaluate data
      this.serverManager.updateState(data)
      this.monitor$.next(this.serverManager.Status) // A)
    })
  timer(1000,1000).subscribe(() => this.monitor$.next(this.serverManager.Status)) // B)
}

getMonitorStatus() : Observable<boolean> {
  return this.monitor$.asObservable()
}
```

In the component

```
public statu$: Observable<boolean> = of(false)

constructor(private svc: DiagnosticsService) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.statu$ = this.svc.getMonitorStatus()
  // Debug - not saving subscription as this is temporary
  this.statu$.subscribe(status => console.log('Status', {status})
}
```

In the View

```
<span [class.running]="statu$ | async"></span>
```

In the above (A) did not result in the view being updated and (B) did. In both cases however the console.log fires with the correct status but the view output is always false when the emit originates from within the afb on() handler.

I eventually resolved the issue by removing the .next() from inside the on() and only relying on the timer - however I am interested to know why this happens.

I am guessing that the reason is that change detection is not firing when the observable is updated from the RTDB on() handler.

My question is - why is this the case?

Comment: `this.monitor$.next(this.serverManager.Status)` are you getting data when you are running this line inside .on in A ?

Comment: Instead `.on` use `.once` method of firebase

Answer (score 0):

put an *ngIf condtion in Span tag and make it false when the emitter is Subscribed and make it after status is Updated
its because the change is not affecting the HTML Screen

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there are NO parts up the chain of observables that are running outside of the `NgZone`. I spent about 4 hours just debugging an async pipe that wouldn't update because there was a `setInterval` buried deep within one of the services that was updating a dependent `Observable`.

I updated the logic in that `setInterval` to run within the `NgZone` and this issue resolved itself and change detection worked as expected.

This might not solve your issue directly, but this was a top thread that came up in my google searching.